# What is the "default" value of a react-native component's flex property?

Tags: react-native

I have a simple Button Component in my react native app, made with just `styled-components`.
This is what it looks like:

```js
const ButtonContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 6px;
  flex-basis: ${props => props.flexBasis || "20%"};
  background: ${props => props.backgroundColor || "orange"};
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: ${props => props.flex || 0};
`;
```

So when I pass in a flex prop like this `<ButtonContainer flex="1" />` I want it to fill the available space. It works as expected.
But when I don't pass in the flex prop, I want it to behave like I never set it. (Don't take up the whole available space).

This does not work. It's still taking up all the available space.
When I get rid of the line `flex: ${props => props.flex || 0};` all together it's working, but I want to set it to `flex: 1` sometimes (reusable component)

**So what is the default `flex` setting in a react-native component?**

I already tried `undefined`, `null` and `-1` but no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

the default value of **flex** property in **react-native** is **0**

Answer (score -2):

setting flex: none worked for me,
so -

```
const Component = styled.View`
  flex: ${props => props.flex || 'none'};
`;
```

Comment: Throws an error for me.

Comment: `undefined` worked